# wlanapi.dll in powershell. Disable background scanning

Tags: powershell, wifi

Looking for some help with a script. I have tried and failed. I am not really advanced in powershell.
importing dlls is new for me. Any help is appreciated.

I want to use powershell to import the wlanapi.dll and use micrsoft native wifi functions to disable wireless background scanning, and enfore streaming mode.

The script should do this on execute. That way I can run it, or set it in a start up script.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlansetinterface?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Functions I am wanting to use:
wlan_intf_opcode_background_scan_enabled
wlan_intf_opcode_media_streaming_mode

Answer (score 0):

Import is something you do via the PSModule paths where your modules or DLLs live.

You must tell PowerShell where the DLL is, no different than you'd have to if you loaded a module (.psm1 file with or without a manifest) of which you did not install to one of the defined PowerShell module paths.

You can use Add-Type...

Add-Type -Path $UncToCustomDll

... yet also, you can also use reflection:

$customDLL = 'UncToYourDLL'
See also Lee Holmes article on the topic here:

[Load a Custom DLL from PowerShell](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell)

If you try to import and it's not in a know location, you get this.

```
Import-Module SomeNewCustomOr3rdP.dll

Import-Module : The specified module 'SomeNewCustomOr3rdP.dll' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

Of course, that error is pretty specific. It has no idea where to find it because that name does not match a module name.

So, this ...

```
Import-Module 'c:\users\mj\desktop\SomeNewCustomOr3rdP.dll'
```

Or create a folder of the same basename as the DLL in the PSModulePath, copy the DLL to the that named folder and use import as normal

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SomeNewCustomOr3rdP\SomeNewCustomOr3rdP.dll'
```

Then this...

```
Import-Module SomeNewCustomOr3rdP
```

... should work as expected. All-in-all, Add-Type, Import-Module, and Reflection.Assembly::LoadFile($customDll), all accomplish the same thing, grant you access to the resource you specified.

If you are using a 3rdP DLL/Module, all this has to be done manually. If you are using published modules/packages that are in the MS powershellgallery.com, then this:

```
# Find all modules with wlan in the name
Find-Module -Name '*wlan*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

# find all packages with wlan in the name
Find-Package -Name '*wlan*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

# Get the detail on wlanapi specifically
Find-Package -Name 'wlanapi'

# Download and save a module or package
Find-Package -Name 'wlanapi' | 
Save-Package -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
Install-Package -Name 'wlanapi' -Force
Import-Module -Name wlanapi
```

Comment: No worries. I know many who hit nuget and other sources to get stuff like this, not knowing the PowerShellGet, can grab most of it and make the use effort easier.

Comment: Thanks. maybe thats what I am missing. The DLL is a windows dll so I didnt think I would have to specify the full path. Does the custom dll method you showed above, work the same as using the builtin windows dll?

 I was looking at other scripts and came up with this, then tried calling it with a function. But your example above shows I may need to approach it diffrently.

$Wlanapi = @'
[DllImport ("wlanapi.dll",EntryPoint = "wlan_intf_opcode_background_scan_enabled")]

    public static extern void wlan_intf_opcode_background_scan_enabled(
        [In] IntPtr pData
    );
'@

Comment: Not sure what I am missinng .  BTW, Thank you for responding.